# save cache in backend side once FE asks to store it explicitly

Tags: caching, microservices, cache-control

the project on which I am working is developed based on microservice architecture.
we placed API-gateway between FE and BE, so every request from FE passes via API-gateway.
in this gateway, we are storing the response from microservices inside the cache and on the next call from FE we return it from the cache.

now the problem is we are storing the response of every request in the cache, we want to give that control to FE, which means FE will tell us which response they want to store it in a cache.

for example, if they are calling two APIs, they can tell API-gateway to store the result of `companies` in cache but don't store `users` response.

1. `/api/companies`
2. `/api/users`

for user's request, we can pass header like `Cache-Control: no-store`, by this way api-gateway will not store it in cache.

but for `companies` request is it fine to pass `Cache-Control: store` in headers?

I was checking this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) but it is not mentioned there how to ask to BE to store it in a cache.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard way for a client to hint that an intermediate cache *should* store the response.

The response from the origin microservice should indicate how the response *can* be cached, and the next request from the FE indicates what it will accept.

> we can pass header like `Cache-Control: no-store`, by this way api-gateway will not store it in cache.

To take effect, this will need to be in the response from the microservice.

In your case, if it's reasonable for these responses to be cached for some consumers, your microservice cache-control should indicate that. Your API gateway will then store them, and front-end clients can opt in to accepting a cached response.